# Need help running an EJB app

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

While trying to run an app-client Main method, I keep getting the following error:

> org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.UserError: ACC007: The app client
>   directory C:\Projects\MyFirstJMSQueue does not contain a manifest; the
>   app client container cannot process it. Embedded programs should pass
>   URIs with scheme "jar:" for JAR files and scheme "file:" for
>   directories. Java Result: 1

When I searched for a solution I found a guide in this [link](http://www.java.net/node/700937) but I don't know how I should configure EAR's properties to the client and run the EAR itself?

Is there somebody can help me?

Comment: me too.  see:  https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21215